# how to change my value for int or str (vice versa)

Tags: python, mysql, string, int

I'm having an issue where my code gives me:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()
```

Thing is, I don't know how to switch my values from str to int or vice-versa :

```
def separate(seq):
    result=[0,0];
    a=0
    b=0
    for c in seq:
        if(c=='0'):
            a+=1
        elif(c=='1'):
            b+=1   
        else:
            c>=2,
            pass

    return result
```

and

```
cursor1=mydb.cursor()

statement ="SELECT prediction FROM splicingdb.proteinsignalexperimental, splicingdb.disorderpredictions where proteinsignalexperimental.ID = disorderpredictions.ID AND source regexp 'disprot'"

cursor1.execute(statement)

resultat = cursor1.fetchall()

#print (resultat)

in [statement]: int(i)

s=statement

print(resultat)

zero, one = separate(s);

print ("zero: %d"%zero)

print ("one: %d"%one)
```

Comment: What is `c>=2` supposed to do? It's not in an `if` statement. What line is the error happening on?

Comment: i just put it there because all my answer is 0 and 1, so i just dont want any valor except those one .. (i could have put it in a better form i guess..)

Comment: Is this your actual code? the indentation looks odd. Why is `result=[0,0];` indented with one space, and `a=0` indented with two? I would expect an `IndentationError`, not a `TypeError`.

Comment: it was my mistake when i put it in the forum.. they have the same indented space

Comment: And `c>=2`, `pass` and `return result` are all indented within the `else`, but all at different levels?

Comment: Since indentation is critical for python, please fix it so all the indentation is correct. Paste your code, mark it, and use the `{}` tool to make it literal code.

Comment: If that line is just supposed to be a comment, put `#` before it.

Comment: I meant the `{}` tool in the StackOverflow toolbar, not putting `{}` characters around the pasted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
else:       # 
    c>=2,   #<----- Not sure what that is, but maybe you want to get rid of it! 
    pass    #<----- I suggest to get rid of the whole "else" block.
```

that code compares c to an int.
the preceding if-elif are comparing c to  strings:

```
if(c=='0'):
...
elif(c=='1'):
...
```

c are the elements of statement.
and
statement ="SELECT prediction FROM host.proteinsignalexperimental, host.disorderpredictions where proteinsignalexperimental.ID = disorderpredictions.ID AND source regexp 'disprot'"

c is a str that you are comparing to an int in what appears to be a syntactic error (or a very strange syntax) in following your else.

if you want to change your variable type, you could do like this:

```
c = int(c)  #<--- changes c to int
# or    
c = str(c)  #<--- changes c to str
```

or do the comparisons without changing the type:

```
int(c) == 2    # <--- Choose which applies to your data.
str(c) == '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your actual `separate` code looks like this, once you adjust for the indentation errors:

```
def separate(seq):
    result=[0,0];
    a=0
    b=0
    for c in seq:
        if(c=='0'):
            a+=1
        elif(c=='1'):
            b+=1   
        else:
            c>=2,
            pass
    return result
```

The line `c>=2,` is giving a `TypeError` because you're trying to compare the character `c` with the integer `1`. Looks like you intended for that line to merely be a comment anyway, so just prefix it with a pound sign.

```
#c>=2,
```

Or just drop the `else` clause entirely.

```
    for c in seq:
        if(c=='0'):
            a+=1
        elif(c=='1'):
            b+=1
    #no else needed here!
    return result
```

(By the way, you probably mean to do `return [a,b]`. Returning `result` will always give you [0,0] no matter what `seq` contains)